# Why do I get an 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER''-error in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In SQL Query Analyzer I run this statement and I don't get anny error:

```
string select = "SELECT " +
"aanvrager.werknemersnaam AS melder , hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_titel, " +
"hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_omschrijving, hd_aanvraag_fase.fase_datum, " +
"hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau_omschrijving AS 'Niveau 1', " +
"hd_melding_niveau_2.niveau_omschrijving AS 'Niveau 2', " +
"hd_aanvragen.outlook_id" +
"FROM hd_aanvragen " +
"INNER JOIN hd_meldingen         ON hd_meldingen.melding_id      =  hd_aanvragen.melding_id " +
"INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_1  ON  hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau1_id = hd_meldingen.niveau1_id " +
"INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_2  ON  hd_melding_niveau_2.niveau2_id = hd_meldingen.niveau2_id " +
"INNER JOIN hd_aanvraag_fase     ON hd_aanvraag_fase.aanvraag_id =  hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_id " +
"INNER JOIN hd_statussen ON hd_statussen.status_id =  hd_aanvraag_fase.status_id " +
"INNER JOIN  hd_werknemers AS oplosser ON oplosser.werknemer_Id =  hd_aanvraag_fase.werknemer_Id " +
"INNER JOIN hd_werknemers  AS aanvrager ON aanvrager.werknemer_Id =  hd_aanvragen.werknemer_Id " +
"WHERE hd_statussen.status_id = 16";
```

But if I run this select-statement here:

```
MyDataSource.SelectCommand = select;
```

I get this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: That is one nasty query!

Comment: It's joining many tables together and it's not very readable. I would put the required logic into a stored procedure, or at least expose these results through a view so that the code itself does not get cluttered. You can see yourself how easy it is to make errors with this kind of code (you missed a whitespace on one of the 14 lines)

Comment: "+" is not necessary in the code . Just a small advice, dont code using query analyzer, it would be very hard to redo it or change a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this bit:

```
"hd_aanvragen.outlook_id" +
"FROM hd_aanvragen " +
```

So your SQL will contain:

```
hd_aanvragen.outlook_idFROM hd_aanvragen
```

I don't think you meant that... (note the lack of space that the end of the first line quoted above)

Suggestions:

- Consider using stored procs, an ORM, or anything else that keeps such huge SQL out of your C# code
- Potentially read SQL from a text file
- Use a verbatim string literal, assuming your data source can handle line breaks in its SQL:

  ```
  string select = @"SELECT 
      aanvrager.werknemersnaam AS melder , hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_titel,
      hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_omschrijving, hd_aanvraag_fase.fase_datum,
      hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau_omschrijving AS 'Niveau 1', 
      ...
      WHERE hd_statussen.status_id = 16";
  ```

Also, if you're going to claim:

> In SQL Query Analyzer I run this statement and I don't get anny error

make sure you're *actually* running the same SQL query. Copy the *actual* value of `select` in the debugger, paste it into SQL Query Analyzer and you'll see exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

This line is missing a space at the end:

```
 "hd_aanvragen.outlook_id" +
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a whitespace before "FROM"

```
"hd_aanvragen.outlook_id" +
"FROM hd_aanvragen "
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the correct source code? Than you are missing a space in the line

```
"hd_aanvragen.outlook_id" +
```

This should be

```
"hd_aanvragen.outlook_id " +
```